# Is there a word for this behaviour?

Tags: offensive-language

Well I use a lot of.. I'm vulgar.. very very perverse (just the language!) at that.. But I value the feelings inclusive of that I honour my enemies (I don't suck up but I value them) whose feelings I value, under their uncouth exteriors - in short, I respect, value and am very sensitive about how others/anyone feels.

I'm not genteel for sure. The freedictionary.com specifies that:

```
      genteel: 2. Free from vulgarity or rudeness.
```

Now I'm not in the former (I'm far from "free from vulgarity") but I detest rudeness. So how would you describe me? What is the exact word/words? Has my condition ever been addressed in the English vocabulary? (It could be crack or nut but I can't be sure. There should be a more colloquial term shouldn't there?
Thank you immensely!

Comment: Sensitive yet uncouth? A rough diamond? Salt of the earth?

Comment: It sounds like your manners are polite, but your language is not. I'm not sure there's a word for that.

Comment: Perhaps you're *coarse.*

Comment: you are just _ill-mannered_

Comment: You say you are "very sensitive about how others/anyone feels." Yet vulgar language is liable to upset people's feelings. Are you perhaps - confused or conflicted?

Comment: well it's just that along with feeling empathy and kindness,I'm capable of feeling violently angry explosively. and it ebbs away rapidly. this could possibly be the residual effects of an acute motor vehicle trauma but there are situations where anyone could (easily) expect me to become "easily" angry or violent as per se, but as always, I point out why they are morose for expecting me to behave so. In short, I have a very good reason for how I feel. In epitomy to my demeanour, I'm nothing but fair and tragically pissed off at unfair people. and when I am in fact pissed off, I don't hold back.

Comment: far from confused and dwelling on conflicted

Comment: far from confused but yes, dwelling on conflicted. but not guilty. just the inability to accept the World for what it is. This is not how I knew the World to be before I fell into coma. Maybe it was and I was just too naive. I've come to accept that, but I don't hold myself to question for feeling how I feel towards how tragically diabolical the World is and everyone are. this is just too unreal.

Comment: but no, I don't mean to seek counsel, but a word to describe my temperament. foul-mouthed seems to do the trick but it's quite plainly derogatory. or is this, like my previous question about "reverse-succession" a situation that has never been addressed before?

Comment: I meant to say "far from confused 'but' dwelling on conflicted"

Comment: any normal person is insensitive towards another interacting adversely towards that person unless the person has a social inferiority-complex or disorder.youre peevish.are you perhaps a troll? go away

Answer (score 1):

[Foul-mouthed](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/foul-mouthed?s=t) appears to fit the bill quite nicely - it has obvious negative connotations but is not necessarily a disparaging label